# Extract value from nested List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am a kotlin newbie and stuck with a basic issue.

I have a data class which looks like:

```
data class ResponseInfo (
    val nameList: List<PersonResponse>
)

data class PersonResponse(
    val personId: Long,
    val fees: List<SalaryInfo>? = null
)

data class SalaryInfo(
    val id: Long?,
    val salaryType: String?,
    val salaryAmount: Double?
)
```

In my project, I am getting the `ResponseInfo` object and I need to get the `salaryAmount` field. I am trying it with the usual java 8 streams way but not able to extract that field.

In kotlin we have something as `flatMap` and may be we can use that but I am not sure how to.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT :**

I need to salaryAmount only when the salaryType is MONTHLY.

This is the json response from which I need to extract `salaryAmount`:

```
{
    "nameList": [
        {
            "personId": 123,
            "fees": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "salaryType": "MONTHLY",
                    "salaryAmount": 5.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you want to collect all `salaryAmount` in list ? or you just want first one ?

Comment: Hey, I would need the `salaryAmount` when it is of MONTHLY type. So for a particular personId there would be only 1 salaryAmount.

Comment: The question is still confusing, i would suggest to add some example with input and output

Comment: I have added the json response that I am getting

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
val salaryAmount = this.nameList.first { it.personId == 1L }.fees?.first { it.salaryType == "MONTHLY" }?.salaryAmount
```

or if you intend some frequent use:

```
data class PersonResponse(val personId: Long, val fees: List<SalaryInfo>? = null) {

    val monthly: SalaryInfo?
        get() { return this.salary("MONTHLY") }
    
    private fun salary(type: String): SalaryInfo? {
        return this.fees?.first { it.salaryType == type }
    }

}

data class ResponseInfo (val nameList: List<PersonResponse>) {

    private fun person(id: Long): PersonResponse? {
        return this.nameList.first { it.personId == id }
    }
    
    fun test() { // example of how this works
        val monthlyAmount = this.person(1L)?.monthly?.salaryAmount
    }
    
}
```

To go a bit further I'd put my constant, like MONTHLY in an enum class

Comment: Hey, this is very close to what I am expecting. But instead of `fees?.first { it.salaryType == "MONTHLY" }` if I have to use `fees?.filter { it.salaryType == "MONTHLY" }` , then how will I get salaryAmount ??

Comment: @Twistleton may be I am not understanding the solution. Is it not making any sense :( ? Does the JSON that I posted help in any way ?

Comment: I find the solution from lorenzo quite appealing.

Comment: fees?.filter { it.salaryType == "MONTHLY" }.map{ it.salaryAmount }.firstOrNull()

Comment: For me as well. Can you help me understand this ? Suppose inside the fees I have 2 values. 1 with salaryType as YEARLY and one with MONTHLY. The `first` would give me the first record from the list or the first record which has salaryType == "Monthly" ?

Comment: Perhaps just try it out

Comment: Only `monthly` as filtered so it'll return that, if element not found matching the predicate it will throw NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @lorenzo It might help if you could split your code across separate lines, and comment the important ones to show what they do.

Comment: So you need to extract an array with the `salaryAmount` values of all `nameList` with `salaryType` set to `MONTHLY`, correct? Can we assume that the JSON has already been decoded?

Comment: **The details are as follows:** The `nameList` will always contain 1 record. It is the response of an API which takes argument as a list and returns a list. In my case I will be calling the endpoint per personId, so the request list will contain only 1 record and hence the response will also contain only 1 record.
But it is possible that I may have multiple values in the `fees` list `(Weekly OR Monthly OR Yearly )`. So I just need to select the `Monthly` and return that particular `salaryAmount`. If there is a better way to achieve this than mentioned by @Lorenzo, I would appreciate your help

Comment: I've edited my answer for what I would do if you frequently require this function